# Escaping Docker Container

Tags: security, docker, containers

I have installed a Docker on my Ubuntu machine 16.04.

Is there any way to bypass Docker container to host? (RCE, Privilege Escalation etc..) Which means is there any way to access the host machine inside the docker container.

Below is the command which I am using it to launch the container.

```
docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:16.04
```

I am going to give docker containers access in my college for testing purpose. And, I have hosted everything on my personal cloud. Is it possible to compromise the host machine from the container?

Please let me know about this. Before I start giving access in my college I need to make sure about it.

PS: I have configured macvlan and containers cannot talk to each other.

Thanks!!

Comment: This is not quite what you are asking about, but it is worth knowing that [docker run allows any host user with docker run access to root the host](https://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2017/09/30/root-your-docker-host-in-10-seconds-for-fun-and-profit/)

Comment: Also, this may be a better question for security stack exchange.

Comment: Thanks Paul for replying. I will post the same question on security stack exchange too.

Comment: If there is a way with the options you've included, then that would be a security vulnerability in docker or the kernel itself, both of which are quick to release patches when vulnerabilities are found.